# Why the error "ORA-00904: invalid identifier" appears in this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors, ora-00904

I've built the following query, but when I try to run it raises the error:

```
ORA-00904: "CASE_MASTER"."FOLLOWUP_DATE":
           invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause: 
*Action: Error at Line: 76 Column: 14
```

Can you give me a hint or show me what is wrong?

**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT case_event_assess.case_id
  FROM case_event        ce
      ,case_event_assess
      ,lm_datasheet
      ,case_product      cp
      ,case_assess       ca
/* New AC Name: Exp: Testing query */
 WHERE ce.case_id = case_master.case_id
   AND ce.case_id = case_event_assess.case_id
   AND ce.seq_num = case_event_assess.event_seq_num
   AND case_event_assess.case_id = case_master.case_id
   AND ca.case_id = case_master.case_id
   AND ca.case_id = case_event_assess.case_id
   AND lm_datasheet.datasheet_id = case_event_assess.datasheet_id
   AND (sheet_name = 'IB' OR license_id = 0)
   AND ce.case_id = cp.case_id
   AND cp.seq_num = case_event_assess.prod_seq_num
   AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM lm_product lp
         WHERE lp.drug_code = cp.co_drug_code
            OR lp.product_id = cp.pat_exposure )
   AND case_master.state_id > 1
   AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT DISTINCT case_event_assess.case_id
          FROM case_event_assess
         WHERE case_event_assess.case_id = case_master.case_id
           AND case_master.rpt_type_id IN (1, 3)
           AND EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM lm_license
                 WHERE lm_license.license_id = case_event_assess.license_id
                   AND lm_license.country_id IN (223, 23000101)
                   AND lm_license.license_type_id IN (4, 6))
        )
   AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM lm_license
               ,case_event_assess cea
         WHERE cea.case_id = case_master.case_id
           AND cea.prod_seq_num = case_event_assess.prod_seq_num
           AND cea.license_id = lm_license.license_id
           AND lm_license.manufacturer_id IN (10087, 200000016, 202000406, 202000608, 202000609)
           AND lm_license.country_id = 223 )
 GROUP BY case_event_assess.case_id
         ,case_event_assess.event_seq_num
         ,case_event_assess.prod_seq_num

HAVING(
(/* Serious */
MIN(ce.sc_death) = 1 OR MIN(ce.sc_threat) = 1 OR MIN(ce.sc_disable) = 1 OR MIN(ce.sc_int_req) = 1
 OR MIN(ce.sc_cong_anom) = 1 OR MIN(ce.sc_hosp) = 1 OR MIN(ce.med_serious) = 1 OR MIN(ce.sc_other) = 1
)
AND
( /* Unlisted*/
MIN(decode(lm_datasheet.datasheet_id, 0, 1, NULL, 1, abs(det_listedness_id - 2))) = 0
 OR MIN(decode(lm_datasheet.datasheet_id, 0, 3, NULL, 3, det_listedness_id)) = 3
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no table called `case_master` in your `from`-clause you can't use it in your `where`-clause.

Comment: Hi, so it should look like this:
SELECT DISTINCT case_event_assess.case_id

FROM case_event ce, case_event_assess, lm_datasheet, case_product cp, case_assess ca, case_master

Comment: I've tried to add the case_master to from clause and i hit another error now:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 72 Column: 10

Comment: For the 2nd error i received. I corrected it by doing the following:

modified this : SELECT DISTINCT case_event_assess.case_id, case_master.followup_date

and group by: with this : GROUP BY case_event_assess.case_id, case_event_assess.event_seq_num, case_event_assess.prod_seq_num, case_master.followup_date
HAVING

now the query is running. ok. Thanks for the tip piet.t